# How to escape special symbols in "term" query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I try to find records in elastic using "term". Like this:

```
bool: {
            must: [
              {term: {"contexts.key": "resource"}},
              {term: {"contexts.tag.name": 'billing/partner_accounts'}}
            ]
          }
```

But search request returns nothing. Looks like it's waiting to escape slash symbol inside my term sentence. So... I tried next variants: 'billing/partner_account', 'billing/partner_account', 'billing\/partner_account'. It didn't give success result. If replace "term" with "match" it will return results for "contexts.tag.name" that include "billing" or "partner_accounts" substrings. But I need to exact matching. Can you please explain what should I to do. Thanks

Comment: in your index mapping what datatype you are using for your field ```contexts.key``` & ```contexts.tag.name```? For using ```term``` query you need to use ```keyword``` datatype. Ref - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html

Comment: Please provide your index mapping, this is most likely some text analysis issue.

Comment: thanks guys, yeah looks like it should have "keyword" type.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was resolved with adding "keyword" to field's name, like

```
term: { "contexts.tag.name.keyword": 'bla-bla-bla' }
```